# How to mix queryset

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of 150 URLs from 15 domains.

They are in the following order:

```
google .com/34534
google .com/4574
google .com/456456
yahoo .com/567567
yahoo .com/34534
yahoo .com/567
yahoo .com/345345
bing .com/345345
bing .com/546546
bing .com/56456
```

But I want to sort it so that the same domains may not come after each other. So I want to mix all URLs. How can I do this? I want the following:

```
google.com/456456
yahoo.com/567567
google .com/34534
yahoo .com/34534
bing .com/546546
yahoo .com/567
bing .com/56456
yahoo.com/345345
google .com/4574
bing .com/345345
```

How can I mix URLs?

Comment: It's called copy/paste. You do that 75 times, or less.

Comment: This is not a job for Npp, If you have linux, use `shuf` command.